# Multiple citations using biblatex, ordering by year using parencite and textcite

Tags: citations, biblatex

The bibliography is arranged in ascending order of names of authors which is fine since the sorting style is nyt. But when I do multiple citations in one parencite{}, the citations are sorted by name. I want to sort it by year as in the oldest one is sorted earliest.

Please suggest if there is any other citestyle to solve above problem?

I am using the following biblatex setting:

`\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=authoryear-comp, uniquelist=false, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, uniquename=false, hyperref=true]{biblatex}`

I am using `\parencite{xyz2002observations, abc2006observed}`. Then the output is

(ABC et al. 2006, XYZ et al. 2002).

But instead I want

(XYZ et al. 2002, ABC et al. 2006)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. You can freely order the authors you cite from by using the command `\parencites`.

To refer to your example, this would give the desired output:

```
\parencites{xyz2002observations}{abc2006observed}.
```

So you have to take care in what order you write the citations here.
Latex will not sort these at all.

Answer (score 0):

I worked another way for now. I added another attribute `sortcites=false` to the above biblatex setting:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=authoryear-comp, uniquelist=false, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, uniquename=false, hyperref=true, sortcites=false]{biblatex}
```

The only thing now is that I add and order manually items in `\parencite` command. So now if I write `\parencite{xyz2002observations, abc2006observed}` it shows -

(XYZ et al. 2002, ABC et al. 2006)